# Open browser popup on APIrequest nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to open a browser popup for client site on rest api request to nodejs backend.
I had tried

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello' });
```

But it still returning html codes as data to the client.
I also used `window.open` but `window is not defined` in server side

Is there anyway to make my backend redirect or render html form on api request!

the following image is how the client get response

[image: Response Output]

Comment: Please post code how you are doing in client

Comment: do i need client code?I am calling this api from react app using axios! Everything I want to do is to open that index file on browser on api call from client @Sumeet

Comment: If you want to open any popup you do it on the client side. You can't open popups from server. In order to make window like a popup, you will need to specify additional parameters to `window.open()` like this for example `var mywindow = window.open('', 'Title', 'width=600,height=450');`. The important here is the third argument `'width=600,height=450'` it will force the window to popup from the browser

Comment: So, basically I can't make my backend open new popup browser from backend.I am really confused, I think I can make like paypal redirect url.

Comment: @Bwar you can't make your backend render popups, but you can set a variable on the backend and when the front end is loaded check the state of the variable and depending on it do something for example open popup. The actual popup opening is done on the front end

Answer (score 0):

If you want the browser change page/view, you need something like `location.href = /yourview.html`

If you want fill your popup with html built on the server, you need to get it using `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` or something built on top of them (for example axios, like you did) and then attach to the dom. 
Once you got it, you can show the popup. But you are on the client side.

res.render return rendered html. http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.render

Comment: i was using react js, It dosen't work on react, how to render html from the response JSON Object on the client side. thank advance